# What is the value of mPlaceHolderBitmap in the Android Developer Page?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Development and I am trying to replicate the example of displaying images on a gridview using Async Task as illustrated on Google's Android Development Page.
My question is: How do I declare or initialize mPlaceHolderBitmap under the following code:
Here is the link to the Google code:
[Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)

```
 public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                new AsyncDrawable(getResources(), mPlaceHolderBitmap, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
```

Comment: It represents your own `Bitmap` to be used as a placeholder while the actual image is loaded. You can download the sample and see the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting [@Luksprog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493939/luksprog)'s comment into an answer:

> It represents your own Bitmap to be used as a placeholder while the actual image is loaded. You can download the sample and see the entire code.